# Why am I getting an incomplete type error when using dirent.h on Windows?

Tags: c, makefile, directory-structure

I have a C project that combines multiple .c and .h files. Previously I just had all of these files in the top level directory, along with the following Makefile:

```
O = o
E =
CC = gcc
OUT = cusum$E
CFLAGS = -D_GNU_SOURCE -O3 -Wall -Wextra --static
DEPS = bessel.h detector.h io.h stepfit.h lmmin_int64.h utils.h
ODIR = obj
_OBJ = main.$O bessel.$O detector.$O io.$O lmmin_int64.$O stepfit.$O utils.$O
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
LIBS = -lm

$(ODIR)/%.$O: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean win

clean:
    rm -f $(OUT) $(ODIR)/*.$O *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
    rm -f $(OUT).exe w$(ODIR)/*.obj *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~

win:
    $(MAKE) CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc E=.exe O=obj ODIR=wobj
```

This works fine as far as I can tell.

I then reorganized things, putting the `.c` files in a `src` folder and the `.h` files in a `lib` folder. I changed the Makefile to the following:

```
O = o
E =
CC = gcc
OUT = dist/cusum$E
CFLAGS = -D_GNU_SOURCE -O3 -Wall -Wextra --static
INCDIR = lib/
DEPS = lib/*.h
ODIR = build/obj
_OBJ = main.$O bessel.$O detector.$O io.$O lmmin_int64.$O stepfit.$O utils.$O
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
LIBS = -lm

$(ODIR)/%.$O: src/%.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) $(LIBS)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean win cleanwin

clean:
    rm -f $(OUT) $(ODIR)/*.$(O) *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~

win:
    $(MAKE) CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc E=.exe O=obj ODIR=build/wobj
    
cleanwin:
    $(MAKE) clean CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc E=.exe O=obj ODIR=build/wobj
```

Now, when I compile for Linux (`make`), it works OK. When I cross-compile for windows (`make win`), I get the following error:

```
`make[1]: Entering directory '[...]'

x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -o build/wobj/main.obj src/main.c -D_GNU_SOURCE -O3 -Wall -Wextra --static -Ilib/ -lm

In file included from lib/io.h:31:0,
                 from src/main.c:21:

/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/dirent.h:41:21: error: field ‘dd_dta’ has incomplete type
  struct _finddata_t dd_dta;
                     ^~~~~~

/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/dirent.h:88:22: error: field ‘dd_dta’ has incomplete type
  struct _wfinddata_t dd_dta;
```

`

`main.c` includes all the libraries via:

```
#include"lib1.h"
#include"lib2.h"
....
```

and is located in the `src` folder

If I return the folder structure to what it was before and use the old Makefile, it works and tests fine, so I think the issue lies in the Makefile rather than the code itself. Can anyone point me in the right direction? If any information is missing, please let me know so I can fix it.

Comment: regarding: `#include"lib1.h"
#include"lib2.h"`  This only includes the header files, not the actual libraries

Comment: You're right, but I'm confused. That part does not change between what works and what doesn't, only the folder structure and the Makefile. What is the proper way to include libraries in that case?

Comment: Although I might organize the makefile a bit differently (build for win is recursive, but linux is not--the usual is to build them in a similar manner). The issue is that, under `mingw`, the standard `dirent.h` has a problem. You'll need to look at that file and find out why things aren't defined properly. The entire definition of `struct _finddata_t` needs to be defined _before_ it is used in `dirent.h`. This may not be _your_ problem.

Comment: the error messages say there is a problem with a header file.  That header file is not included when doing a direct compile, however is included when you do the cross compile.  Please (at least) examine that 'bad' header file (or better, post that header file as part of your question

Comment: @user3629249 but it is being included if I do the crosscompile using the Makefile with a different folder structure. Nothing changes about any part of the code between the cross compilation that works and the one that doesn't. Only the folder structure and the Makefile

Comment: @CraigEstey that would be my first instinct, except that it works when using the first Makefile and having all the source/headers in the top level folder and only fails when using the second Makefile and organizing them a bit better. As far as I can tell, the problem is with the second Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason in file io.h. When you moved io.h to subdirectory, dirent.h wants to include your file instead of system one.

```
#include <io.h>
```

To resolve this situation, just rename your io.h.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the windows version of MinGW has some definition issues. The following code added to my compiler's version of `include/dirent.h` fixed the problem for me. Editing library functions is probably a bad idea generally, so only use this if you're feeling adventurous... I make no claims that this won't break all the things elsewhere.

```
#ifndef _FSIZE_T_DEFINED
typedef unsigned long   _fsize_t;
#define _FSIZE_T_DEFINED
#endif

struct _finddata_t
{
    unsigned    attrib;     /* Attributes, see constants above. */
    time_t      time_create;
    time_t      time_access;    /* always midnight local time */
    time_t      time_write;
    _fsize_t    size;
    char        name[FILENAME_MAX]; /* may include spaces. */
};

struct _wfinddata_t
{
    unsigned    attrib;     /* Attributes, see constants above. */
    time_t      time_create;
    time_t      time_access;    /* always midnight local time */
    time_t      time_write;
    size_t  size;
    wchar_t     name[FILENAME_MAX]; /* may include spaces. */
};
```